# osCommerce Redirecting To Credit Card Step on Confirmation Page

Tags: php, e-commerce, oscommerce, authorize.net

Previously I had an issue where the SSL Cert was not working properly but that had been taking care of. However, the current issue is as follows:

Click Item to put in basket -- Success
Step 1 - Select Delivery    -- Success 
Step 2 - Enter valid CC# (using authorize.net test cc#) -- Success
Step 3 - Order Confirmation .. Shows me my order, when I click 'Confirm Order' it fails and kicks back to Step 2, prompting them for Credit Card information.

Does anyone know the source of this? Perhaps at the Authorize.net part is not retrieving the correct information?

Has anyone else had a similar situation?

Thanks.

Comment: This is certainly worth also posting in osCommerce's or the payment module's forum / support site. It could be that it doesn't find a solution here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, seems I've come to the conclusion:

Whenever it bounces back to enter the CC# again it's actually going to:
https://secure.authorize.net/gateway/transact.dll

Viewing the source of the page shows

```
<HTML><BODY><H3>The following errors have occurred.</H3>(13) The merchant login ID or password is invalid or the account is inactive.<BR></BODY></HTML>
```